# No specs are being found in jasmine options file

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-node

I have a jasmine.options.js file and have defined some suites inside

```
module.exports = {
   suites: {
     first: [
         '../**/*.spec.js',
     ],
     second: [
         '../anotherpath/**/*.spec.js'
     ]

  }
};
```

I also have a script in the package jason called jasminetest where I specify the path of this jasmine options as the config file
Goes like this:

```
"jasminetest": "jasmine --config=./jasmine.options.js"
```

Then in my terminal I try to run

```
npm run jasminetest
```

or

```
npm run jasminetest -- --filter=first
```

But the result is "No specs found"

I know the specs route is correct and the file path for the jasmine options is also correct. I wonder if I'm missing something?